# Converting long to wide when some observations have more than one time variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I just want each ID to have one row. Some of them have 2 of a different ID, and I want to make the dataset wide like in the sample output below.

```
ID.   other_ID.  height   color 
44    57          56      blue
32    99          28      green
66    23          19      yellow
66    56          5       purple
80    43          7       green
```

```
ID    other_ID    other_ID2   height1    height2    color1    color2 
44     57           NA           56        NA        blue      NA
32     99           NA           28        NA        green     NA
66     23           56           19        5         yellow    purple
80     43           NA           7         NA        green     NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  "ID." = c(44, 32, 66, 66, 80),
  "other_ID." = c(57, 99, 23, 56, 43),
  "height" = c(56, 28, 19, 5, 7),
  "color" = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "green")
)
```

Here’s an idea using `tidyverse`. The idea is to use the non-unique ID column to create a count of the number of observations within that ID, then use that count to convert the data to wide format.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_wide <-
  df %>%
  group_by(ID.) %>%
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID., values_from = c(other_ID., height, color), names_from = obs)
```

```r
df_wide
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID. [4]
#>     ID. other_ID._1 other_ID._2 height_1 height_2 color_1 color_2
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1    44          57          NA       56       NA blue    <NA>   
#> 2    32          99          NA       28       NA green   <NA>   
#> 3    66          23          56       19        5 yellow  purple 
#> 4    80          43          NA        7       NA green   <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple pivot_wider:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count_id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(other_ID, height, color), names_from = count_id)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
     ID other_ID_1 other_ID_2 height_1 height_2 color_1 color_2
  <int>      <int>      <int>    <int>    <int> <chr>   <chr>  
1    44         57         NA       56       NA blue    <NA>   
2    32         99         NA       28       NA green   <NA>   
3    66         23         56       19        5 yellow  purple 
4    80         43         NA        7       NA green   <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R:

```
reshape(transform(df, time = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along)), dir = 'wide', idvar = 'ID', sep="")
  ID other_ID1 height1 color1 other_ID2 height2 color2
1 44        57      56   blue        NA      NA   <NA>
2 32        99      28  green        NA      NA   <NA>
3 66        23      19 yellow        56       5 purple
5 80        43       7  green        NA      NA   <NA>
```

in Data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID~rowid(ID), value.var = names(df)[-1], sep = "")

   ID other_ID1 other_ID2 height1 height2 color1 color2
1: 32        99        NA      28      NA  green   <NA>
2: 44        57        NA      56      NA   blue   <NA>
3: 66        23        56      19       5 yellow purple
4: 80        43        NA       7      NA  green   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c(44L, 32L, 66L, 66L, 80L),
  other_ID = c(57L, 99L, 23L, 56L, 43L),
  height = c(56L, 28L, 19L, 5L, 7L),
  color = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "green")
)

dcast(setDT(df), ID ~ rowid(ID), value.var = names(df)[-1])

#>    ID other_ID_1 other_ID_2 height_1 height_2 color_1 color_2
#> 1: 32         99         NA       28       NA   green    <NA>
#> 2: 44         57         NA       56       NA    blue    <NA>
#> 3: 66         23         56       19        5  yellow  purple
#> 4: 80         43         NA        7       NA   green    <NA>
```

---

A solution based on `nest` and `unnest_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  nest(data = c(other_ID, height, color)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(data) %>% unnest_wider(other_ID, names_sep = "") %>% 
  unnest_wider(height, names_sep = "") %>% unnest_wider(color, names_sep = "")

#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>      ID other_ID1 other_ID2 height1 height2 color1 color2
#>   <int>     <int>     <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1    44        57        NA      56      NA blue   <NA>  
#> 2    32        99        NA      28      NA green  <NA>  
#> 3    66        23        56      19       5 yellow purple
#> 4    80        43        NA       7      NA green  <NA>
```

---

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ str_c(., collapse = ",")), .groups ="drop") %>% 
  reduce(names(.)[-1], function(x,y) 
    separate(x,y, into=str_c(y,1:2), sep=",", fill="right", convert=T), .init=.)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>      ID other_ID1 other_ID2 height1 height2 color1 color2
#>   <int>     <int>     <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1    32        99        NA      28      NA green  <NA>  
#> 2    44        57        NA      56      NA blue   <NA>  
#> 3    66        23        56      19       5 yellow purple
#> 4    80        43        NA       7      NA green  <NA>
```